# Oracle contains with Fuzzy does not return logical result

Tags: oracle, fuzzy-search

I have this query:

```
select id, name from ville where CONTAINS(NAME,'?TROOZ%') > 0;
```

In my table:

- 1679 TROIS-PONTS FOSSE (LIEGE)
- 1680 TROIS-PONTS WANNE (LIEGE)
- 2717 TROOZ (LIEGE)

this query will return only the two first results and not the 2717.

Why TROOZ is not returned ??

I read the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm
And I don't understand why the last entry and the more logical because the entire query is found in text is not returned.

NB: CONTAINS(NAME,'?TROOZ%') return 0 for the name "TROOZ (LIEGE)"

Comment: Did you try with `CONTAINS(NAME,'?TROIS%')`. From the documentation of [`fuzzy`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#i997330) I would understand that the input should match the correct spelling, from which Oracle's algorithm would then generate the fuzzy variations.

Comment: I try to get TROOZ entry so try with TROIS does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

Little late to answer but it would be somehow helpful if you consider this.

```
select id, name from ville where CONTAINS(NAME, 'definescore(fuzzy(TROOZ, 1, 10, weight), relevance)', 1) > 0;
```

Here we are using **definescore** operator based on **relevance**, and then uses **fuzzy** to expand the search results based on similarity **weight**, here we limit the expanded results to 10 with minimum score 1 as an example.

[Fuzzy search](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cqoper.htm#GUID-5BA618D7-45DA-4253-BB0D-313970EA7C5D)

[Define score for relevance](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cqoper.htm#GUID-BEF0570D-8B11-4893-AEFF-0AD7DED185BB)